# IntelliJ database tool keeps indexing all tables when I modify one table

Tags: database, intellij-idea

I am using the database tool in IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.1.

I have a database schema that has about 100 tables using DB2 server. Most of the tables are not related.

During development, I often need to add a new column to an table. However, each time intelliJ will start indexing all the tables and takes very long time. Even the table I modified is not related to any other tables. The table I modify is also a trivial table just for test purpose.

---

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid re-indexing all tables when not necessary?